# How to inject variables, arrays or pre-made objects using $this->get() in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

When inside a controller,

```
$this->get('some_service');
```

gives me an object after creating/injecting the required services into "some_service".

However, if I had a class that had:

```
class SomeClass {

    public function __construct(array $parameterArray, SomeObject $someObject) {
        //...
    }
}
```

which requires some kind of array (defined inside the controller) to be injected into the constructor, is it possible to get the Symfony2 service container to deal with this situation? If so, how could I do it?

Comment: Does the array have to be in the constructor ? You could inject it after instantiation with a setParameters function.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments passed to a service at construction should not depend on state. You should instead pass those arguments to the methods you need, eg

```
class SomeClass {
    public function __construct(SomeObject $someObject) {
        //...
    }

    public function doSomethingWithParameterArray(array $parameterArray) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then simply pass the stateful data in when required, eg

```
$svc = $this->get('some_service');
$result = $svc->doSomethingWithParameterArray($array);
```